# The difference between consecutive primes in arithmetic progressions

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Let $\pi(x)=\sum_{p\leq x}$ denote the prime counting function. [A well known result of Baker, Harman, and Pintz](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/plms/83.3.532) on prime gaps states that for $x\geq y\geq x^{0.525}$ we have that

$$\pi(x+y)-\pi(x)\gg \frac{y}{\log x}.$$

Let $\pi(x;q,a)$ denote the number of primes $p\leq x$ such that $p\equiv a\pmod{q}$. Is there an analogous version of this theorem for $\pi(x;q,a)$?

> **Question:** What is the smallest growing function $f(x,q)$ such that for any $x\geq y\geq f(x,q)$ we have that $$\pi(x+y;q,a)-\pi(x;q,a)\gg \frac{y}{\log x}?$$

Corollary 13.8 of [Montgomery and Vaughn's Multiplicative Number Theory](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/multiplicative-number-theory-i/4E45519B26115AEEA4839C6C38206ACD) states that under Generalized Riemann Hypothesis $$\psi(x;q,a)=\sum_{\begin{array}{c}
n\leq x\\
n\equiv a\ (q)
\end{array}}\Lambda(n)=\frac{x}{\phi(q)}+O\left(x^{1/2}\log^{2}x\right).$$

From this Corollary, it follows that under GRH the desired lower bound holds for $$f(x,q) =  \phi(q)x^\frac{1}{2}\log^{2}(x).$$

I'm aware of a [1933 result of Heilbronn (MR1545353)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01188631), which I believe (my German isn't great) proves that for fixed $q,a$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for $x\geq y\geq x^{1-\delta}$ $$\pi(x+y;q,a)-\pi(x;q,a)\sim \frac{y}{\phi(q)\log x}.$$

Are there any more recent results on this topic?

Comment: In fact the first display holds for $x\geq y\geq x^{0.525}$, not just for  $x\geq y\gg x^{0.525}$

Comment: @GHfromMO: True! I've updated the post.

Comment: The following paper has a good discussion of the kind of results you might be looking for (https://tigerweb.towson.edu/akumchev/a12.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

Unconditionally, one can take $f(x,q)=x^{0.525}$, provided that $q$ is in the Siegel-Walfisz range $q\leq (\log x)^A$.  There exists a (suitably small) constant $\delta>0$ such that one can take $f(x,q)=x^{0.525}$ for all except a density zero subset of $q\leq x^{\delta}$.

This follows from a certain Bombieri-Vinogradov-type result for a carefully constructed lower bound for the indicator function of the primes (due to  [Kumchev](https://academic.oup.com/qjmath/article/53/4/479/1537722?searchresult=1), but with $0.525$ replaced by $0.53$) combined with the second moment bound for $L(s,\chi)^2$ times a Dirichlet polynomial (due to [Harman, Watt, and Wong](https://academic.oup.com/qjmath/article/55/3/307/1577135)).  Full details on how to combine these two results can be found in the work of [Alweiss and Luo](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40993-018-0109-y) (see Theorem 2.3 therein).  One then takes $Q = (\log x)^A$.